# Translate .net application without different forms

Tags: .net, winforms, localization, translation

I plan to translate an .net 2.0 application to different languages. For that I enabled the localizable attribute in every form. The problem with that is, that I have to apply changes to the UI in every language supported. Is there a way to just translate the captions of buttons, labels etc. without "translating" the positon, size etc? I think its easier to fit the forms to all languages once and not to have to maintain every language's layout afterwards.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Localisation pages on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx) and [here (older .NET 1.1 page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309421(VS.71).aspx) and [here (newer .NET 3.5 page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753931.aspx).

The basics is that you create separate `resx` files for each language you want to support and as long as you set it up correctly .NET will sort out which language is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do no create a resource file for translating apps.
Basically i used i use database and google translator online or api(http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2010/05/18/google-translation-api-integration-in-net.aspx).
Here is what i do:
1-I create additional table for each table within the database.For example Customers_FR.
The goal of this table is to translate customer table into another language(french here).
2-I create a master table that will translate each page item on my app.For example let`s say i have a login screen which  usually contains username,password,login and logout.I use this master table to translate login title into another language.But you have to be careful here on how your are defining columns.For example i can name the login page in this table as main_login_username,main_login_password and then set the value to the desired language.
Ex (main_login_username,"Utilisateur") (Key,Value)
3-Lastly you need to create a function that will get values from both master table and and translation tables.This is how i do it and it is a lot easier for customers to change values in database 
I hope it helps
Talley
talley@inbox.com